# MongoDatabase class is not available in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I am trying to use MongoDB as the database in my MVC 4 application.  I was following a tutorial in which he has used MongoDatabase class to access the database. But there is no MongoDatabase class. I have referenced the drivers. same is for getServer().MongoDatabase class and getServer() methods are missing.
Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot, I found the problem. Actually, I was using an older version of MongoDB that is why I needed to reference the "Legacy official c# driver for mongoDB".